# Apollo MockedProvider cannot return data using useLazyQuery with onCompleted

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, testing-library

I am using Apollo Client (3.3.16) MockedProvider and Jest + react testing library to test a component which using useLazyQuery with onCompleted attribute. However, MockedProvider cannot call the onCompleted function (handleData() in my case). After the console.log I found that the onCompleted function has never been triggered. Any ideas how to test component (  in my case)  with useLazyQuery? Appreciated in advance!
My react component code is like this:

```
const handleData = data => { // this function never been called for testing
    setData(data.dataWithFilters.data);
  };

  const [loadData, { loading }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_DATA,
    {
      variables: {
        id: productId,
        first: 999999,
        page: 1,
        isBase: true
      },
      onCompleted: handleData, // never been triggered for testing
      fetchPolicy: "network-only"
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => { // works fine
    loadData({
       variables: {
        id: productId,
        first: 999999,
        page: 1,
        isBase: true
      },
      fetchPolicy: "network-only"
    });
  }, [loadData, productId]);
```

My testing code is:

```
 const renderComponent = (mocksData) => {
    render(
      <MockedProvider
        mocks={mocksData}
        defaultOptions={{
          query: { fetchPolicy: "no-cache" },
          watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' },
        }}
        addTypename={false}
      >
        <ServicesContextProvider freightRateServices={{}}>
          <ContractInformationPageProvider>
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["contracts/311"]}>
              <Route path="products/:productId">
                <ContractInformationPage />
              </Route>
            </MemoryRouter>
          </ContractInformationPageProvider>
        </ServicesContextProvider>
      </MockedProvider>,
      {
        wrapper: BrowserRouter
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Unfortunately when you test your code the way Apollo recommends, 9 out 10 times the tests fail because the mocked response does NOT match the query your production code is executing. As they say in then docs:

> Your test must execute an operation that exactly matches a mock's shape and variables to receive the associated mocked response.

Even if your mock is 98% close, and just off by one field, you will not recieve any data in the test. **Even worse is that you will not be aware of this because it will not log an error, it will just leave your data fields undefined.** So watch very very close what the query fields and variables are and compare to the mock you made.

Comment: Yeah, it was disappointed. Eventually, I took this https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6865#issuecomment-874049155 solution. The idea is to use jest.mock to mock the onCompleted instead of using MockedProvider